# Derived Subgroups G'

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Can someone tell me if the following proposition is true ?

let $G$ be group and $g_i\in G$ for $i=1\ldots n$ for any permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ then we have $g_1g_2\ldots g_ng^{-1}_{\sigma(1)}\ldots g^{-1}_{\sigma(n)} \in G'$

Comment: Did you mean $g_1g_2 \cdots g_n g_{\sigma(1)}^{-1} \cdots g_{\sigma(n)}^{-1}$? If so, then yes.

Comment: @Holk yes, I have forgotten tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:G\to G/G'$ be the canonical surjection. Let $n\geq1$, $g_1,\dots,g_n\in G$, and $\sigma\in S_n$. Since the quotient $G/G'$ is abelian, we have 
\begin{align}
f(g_1\cdots g_ng_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}\cdots g_{\sigma(1)}^{-1})
  &= f(g_1)\cdots f(g_n)f(g_{\sigma(1)}^{-1})\cdots f(g_{\sigma(1)}^{-1})) \\\\
  &= f(g_1)f(g_{\sigma(1)}^{-1})\cdots f(g_n)f(g_{\sigma(n)}^{-1}) \\\\
  &= 0
\end{align}
so that $g_1\cdots g_ng_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}\cdots g_{\sigma(1)}^{-1}$ is in the kernel of $f$, namely, in $G'$.